# RSpec mocking module function of controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

So I'm very new to Rails and struggling a bit with RSpec, specifically mocking certain things.  So I have a module (concern) that a few of my controllers are using.  That module (ValidateAdmin) calls two other functions within, current_user and logged_in_user.  To cover the most possibilities, I wanted to stub both those functions and set their return value.  Any suggestions on how to make this work?

```
describe ValidateAdmin do
  before :all do
    class FakeController < ApplicationController
      include ValidateAdmin
    end
  end

let(:controller) { FakeController.new }

describe '#validate_admin_logged_in' do
  controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(instance_double(User, admin?: true))
  controller.stub(:logged_in_user).and_return(instance_double(User, admin?: true))
  [RSpec contexts go here]
```

Edit - Fixed it by containing my mocking statements inside a 'before' block.  Also just realized stub is deprecated so switched to allow statements.

Comment: what happens right now with your current code?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Sorry for not putting that in the question, I was a bit rushed.  It was throwing a very weird error, although I fixed it by containing it in a 'before' block.  Dumb mistake on my part but thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller instance can be stubbed like any other object. You may also need to add the route:

```
describe FakeController, type: :controller do
  let(:admin_user) { instance_double(User, admin?: true) }

  it "performs my excellent test" do
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(admin_user)
    routes.draw { get "custom_action" => "fake#custom_action" }
    get :custom_action
  end
end
```

`let(:controller)` is uneccessary -- RSpec does that for you. Also, the test class does not need to go into a `before` block -- it can simply be defined at the top of the file, or require-d.

Comment: My problem was with where I had my stub statements - fixed the weird error I was getting by putting it in a 'before' block.  Also changed from stub to allow because I found out that was deprecated.  Thanks!